# Insert into many to many relation table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

In my laravel project, I have tables that i want to insert a many to many relationship between 2 of them. I want to bind an User(that must be a cleaner kind) to one House of many from current Host user authenticated. To do so, I'm implementing the following function in Controller:

```
public function hireCleanerToHouse (Request $request)
{
  $house_id = $request->houseAssign;
  $email = $request->email;
  $house = House::find($house_id);
  $cleanerUser = User::where('email', $email)->first();
  if ($cleanerUser && $house){
    $cleanerUser->houses()->attach($house);
  }

  return response()->json('success', 200);
}
```

May I am missing a detail of logic that cant let me insert any data. Im pretty new using laravel and the Eloquent ORM.

to help understand better, here are the Models from project. The functions that take care of a separates tables (CRUD) are all working fine.

If there are some other tip to improve legibity or if I'm ignoring some best pratice, I will gladly accept it.

**User:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function host()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Host::class);
}

public function cleaner()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Cleaner::class);
}
```

}

**House:**

```
class House extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'host_id'];

protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

protected $appends = ['next_cleaning'];

public function host()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Host::class);
}

public function cleaners()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Cleaner::class,
        'cleaners_houses',
        'house_id',
        'cleaner_id'
    );
}

public function cleanings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CleaningProject::class);
}

public function getNextCleaningAttribute()
{
    return $this->cleanings()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}
}
```

**Cleaner:**

```
class Cleaner extends Model
{
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function houses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        House::class,
        'cleaners_houses',
        'cleaner_id',
        'house_id'
    );
}

public function hosts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Host::class,
        'cleaners_hosts',
        'cleaner_id',
        'host_id'
    );
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function cleanings()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CleaningProject::class);
}

public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->name;
}

}
```

**Host**

```
class Host extends Model
{
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

protected $appends = ['name'];

public function houses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(House::class);
}

public function cleaners()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Cleaner::class,
        'cleaners_hosts',
        'host_id',
        'cleaner_id'
    );
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function getNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->name;
}
}
```

And also the migration that bind many Cleaners to many House is already created:

**Migration**

```
class CreateCleanersHousesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cleaners_houses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('cleaner_id')->references('id')->on('cleaners');
        $table->integer('house_id')->references('id')->on('houses');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('cleaners_houses');
}
```

}

Comment: Can I suggest, cleaning up your presented code, so it's faster and easier to get an overview of what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution that I found:

```
public function hireCleanerToHouse (Request $request)
{
  $email = $request->email;
  $houseId = $request->idHouse;
  $idUserEmail = User::where('email', $email)->first();
  $cleaner = Cleaner::where('user_id', $idUserEmail->id)->first();
  $house = House::find($houseId);
  $cleaner->houses()->attach($house->id);
  return response()->json([$cleaner, $house], 200);
}
```

As you may see the problemn was because the model Cleaner only contains 'id' and 'user_id', so i had to get first the user.id and find the cleaner where user_id = user.id.

Also I don't  passed the  $house->id in the attach() to match the relationship. Its now working fine. hope it helps someone else.